# SELECT * FROM does not return all rows

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, select

I can't find any reference to this error anywhere. I'm running SQL Express 2008 on a local PC and have created a number of tables. All appear to function correctly except one “Contact”. It contains names, phone numbers, etc... and currently has 10 rows in it (not real data, just stuff). When I look into it in Management Studio there are 10 rows but when I execute the following I only get the top 3 rows returned. I've run `DBCC CHECKDB` and got no errors. I can add new lines without problems.

VB.Net code:

```
conString = String.Format("server={0};uid={2};pwd={3};database={1};", server, database, dbID, dbPass)
myConn = New SqlConnection("")

'Open the connection.
myConn.ConnectionString = conString
myConn.Open()

Dim com As String
com = "SELECT * FROM contact"

myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
myCmd.CommandText = com
myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

Do While
   myReader.Read()
   Dim contact As nameClass = New nameClass
   contact.id = myReader.GetInt32(0)
   contact.name = myReader.GetString(1)
   contact.supplierID = myReader.GetInt32(2)
   contact.customerID = myReader.GetInt32(3)
   contact.phone = myReader.GetString(4)
   contact.fax = myReader.GetString(5)
   contact.mobile = myReader.GetString(6)
   contact.email = myReader.GetString(7)
   contact.notes = myReader.GetString(8)
Loop
myReader.Close()
myConn.Close()
```

The database contents from SSMS is:

```
Index Name   Supp  Cust     phone     fax       mobile      eMail          created             user
+--+--------+-----+-----+---------+---------+----------+------------+------------------------+---
16 | fred a | -1  |  -1 | 09809809| 09809809| 090980980| lkjlkjlkjlk| 2011-12-15 11:12:25.000| 3
17 | fred b | -1  |  -1 | 098098  | 09809809| 09809809 | llkjlkjlkkl| 2011-12-15 11:13:02.000| 3
18 | fred c |  1  |  -1 | 0980980 | 09809809| 09809809 | lkjhkljlk  | 2011-12-15 11:13:34.000| 3
19 | fred d | -1  |   2 | 98098098| 09809809| 09809890 | kjhkjhkj   | 2011-12-15 11:13:54.000| 3
1  | John   | -1  | -1  | 89769887| 0980980 | 0980980  | kjhkjkj    | 2011-11-12 23:34:12.000| 3
2  | Bob    | -1  | -1  |         |         |          | ;lk;lkl;   | 2011-11-12 23:40:39.000| 3
3  | Mike   | -1  | -1  |         |         |          |            | 2011-11-12 23:44:18.000| 3
4  | Louise | -1  | -1  | 98798789|         |          |            | 2011-11-12 23:43:38.000| 3
5  | Colin  | -1  | -1  |         |         |          |            | 2011-12-12 10:34:15.000| 3
6  | harry  |  3  | -1  | 93872983|         |          | kasjhkajsh | 2011-12-14 02:16:07.000| 3
```

Comment: Hi, I’m working on a single PC so yes same server. 
I don’t think you can run a trace on SQL Express can you ? 
If I run the SQL request in the analyser I get all 10 records If I run the request from the program I only get 3 records. Same request exactly

Schema is dbo and if Irun dbo.contact it makes no difference.

I do use myReader to iterate through the data and only get 3 loops.

Additional information, I have deleted some records in this table through the edit function in SMS. I have another table also with 10 records in which I have not deleted any records in and that reads OK.

Comment: It's also in a try, catch so I'm getting no errors

Comment: If I made available the database as a download would that helkp ?

Comment: HI guys, sorted it. it was part of the myReader.read loop. Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees. Why oh why are they so obvious when you track them down !!!

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

Are you sure your application is connecting to the same server and database as the one your are connecting to from SQL Management Studio?

You could try running a sql trace and see what query you application is sending to the database.

I'm assuming you are running "SELECT * FROM contact" in query analyzer.  What schema owner, dbo?

Try changing your query to SELECT * FROM dbo.contact" in your application and run the same query from query analyzer.

Also (as suggested in the comment) you will need to iterate over the reader to actually read out the data.